# Cannot create 'Show' segue in navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a Navigation Controller, nothing too fancy. However, when I try to add the next view controller onto the stack with a Show Segue from either the button or the [yellow button at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQUCU.png), the option doesn't appear. I have tried creating a new navigation controller and accompanying view controllers but still nothing. When loading the app I am presented with the initial view controller but the button does nothing, no error either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: These are the options that XCode shows.]

Comment: What version of Xcode is this?  Just to be sure, you are control+dragging from either the yellow dot or the button to the viewController you are trying to segue to, right?  I am unable to reproduce your issue, which is why I want to confirm exactly what you're doing.

Comment: What Xcode version are you using and what iOS version are you targeting?  It looks like Xcode thinks adaptive segues aren't available for your target

Comment: I am using XCode version 3.2.1 and am targeting iOS 10.2 and yes, I have tried control+dragging from the yellow dot and the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use push segue, then click on that segue and from the storyboard editor change it to "Show".

Comment: Xcode still lists the options that are shown in the image above unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and am posting it incase someone else needs some help. There is an option to use trait variations, this needs to be enabled to use push segues.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBSBg.png